# Python Barcode OSError: cannot open resources error while running .exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, barcode

I'm trying to make an application with a module python barcode when I compiled it raw it worked well but when I tried to turn it into an exe (using pyinstaller) this gives me the error

```
 File "barcode\base.py", line 67, in save
 File "barcode\ean.py", line 95, in render
 File "barcode\base.py", line 102, in render
 File "barcode\writer.py", line 188, in render
 File "barcode\writer.py", line 280, in _paint_text
 File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 959, in truetype
 File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 956, in freetype
 File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 247, in __init__
 OSError: cannot open resource
```

Code that I'm currently running

```
bar_code = 310400070000555
bar_code = str(bar_code)
bar_code_obj = EAN13(bar_code, writer=ImageWriter())
bar_code_obj.save("bar_code_img")
```

Comment: Typically this means you're trying to open something that isn't source code but was included in the source tree (a font, I'd presume), but pyinstaller didn't detect it as a dependency. Pyinstaller's documentation goes into great length about how to address this; it's not a reasonable request to ask people to reproduce that information here.

Comment: See in particular https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-data-files-from-a-module